# Using kajiki in TG2.1

Tags: turbogears

the recently released turbogears 2.1 mentioned about the support of kajiki, a genshi-like templating engine, but i cant find any resource on how to get started to use tg2.1 with kajiki. any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I enabled Kajiki in a TG 2.1 project by changing the `<projectname>/config/app_cfg.py` file.
After the line

```
base_config.renderers.append('genshi')
```

just add

```
base_config.renderers.append('kajiki')
```

You can later use a Kajiki template from any of your actions by decorating it with something like

```
 @expose('kajiki:projectname.templates.sometemplate')
```

You can also set Kajiki as the default template language by changing the `base_config.default_renderer` assignment in `app_cfg.py`. If you do this, you won't need the `kajiki:` prefix when decorating, e.g.,

```
@expose('projectname.templates.sometemplate')
```

will suffice.

After this works for you, changing `setup.py` to add a Kajiki dependency is probably all you need in order to have a working project. The only thing I haven't tried as yet is i18n; I'll probably update this answer when I do.